# Django select objects with empty ManyToManyField

Tags: django, join, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

Considering the following models, knowing a family, how do I select Kids with no buyers?

```
class Family...

class Kid(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family)
    buyer = models.ManyToManyField(Buyer, blank=True, null=True)

family = get_object_or_404(Family, pk=1)
for_sale = family.kid_set.filter(buyer... this screws my child trade business
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`family.kid_set.filter(buyer__isnull=True)` should work.

Answer (score 4):

@piquadrat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856361/django-select-objects-with-empty-manytomanyfield/3856477#3856477) is correct. You can *also* do:

```
for_sale = Kid.objects.filter(family__pk = 1, buyer = None)
```

This lets you avoid a separate query to look up the `Family` instance.