# django model:How to filter those with no relative objects in ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, orm, model, manytomanyfield

I've implemented two models, Dialog and PrivateLetter:

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    launcher = models.ForeignKey(User)
    target = models.ForeignKey(User)
    privateletters = models.ManyToManyField(PrivateLetter, related_name='belong_dialogs')

class PrivateLetter(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='send_privateletters')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recv_privateletters')
    release_time = models.DateTimeField()
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Now I want to delete PrivateLetter objects whose `belong_dialogs.count()==0`, but I don't know how to make it **efficiently**.
Sincere thanks!

**SOLVED**

Finally I get answer from:

[Django select objects with empty ManyToManyField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856361/django-select-objects-with-empty-manytomanyfield?rq=1)

```
PrivateLetter.objects.filter(belong_dialogs__isnull=True)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django select objects with empty ManyToManyField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856361/django-select-objects-with-empty-manytomanyfield)